# Error: The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, msbuild, gruntjs

I using grunt msbuild to build a project.  When I run grunt I get the following error:

> Error: The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the  element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format

In the project, it already has this namespace.

The project was authored in vs2019 and .net 4.7.2

The output from grunt looks like:

> Running "copy:bacon" (copy) task Created 7 directories, copied 16
>   files
>
> Running "zip:release" (zip) task File
>   "release/zip/Cogworks.ExamineInspector.1.zip" created.
>
> Running "umbracoPackage:dist" (umbracoPackage) task Package created at
>   release\umbraco\Cogworks.ExamineInspector.1.zip (29082 bytes)
>
> Running "nugetpack:dist" (nugetpack) task Trying to create NuGet
>   package from
>   src/Cogworks.ExamineInspector/Cogworks.ExamineInspector.csproj.  ERROR
>   Error: The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild
>   XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format,
>   please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
>   to the  element. If the project has been authored in the old
>   1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.  C:\code\examineinspector-v2\src\packages\Umbraco.SqlServerCE.4.0.0.1\build\Umbraco.SqlServerCE.targets
>   Warning: Task "nugetpack:dist" failed. Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

And cut down part of project file looks like:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

Comment: Can you provide the contents of the project file, sanitized as necessary? Also, perhaps detailed/verbose output from grunt (in case we can glean from it sanity checks such as which MSBuild assembly is being used and which project file it is attempting to build).

Comment: just updated original post with requested data

Comment: Did you get a fix for this Ismail? I am getting the same error on Azure continuous deployment

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Ok figured this out after paying more attention to the error message.  In packages\Umbraco.SqlServerCE.4.0.0.1\build\Umbraco.SqlServerCE.targets it needed the namepsace i added it there and now it builds.

Issue now is figuring out how to get updated package for that dependancy

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to expand on Ismail's answer.

His solution is correct however if you are wondering on how to add the namespace and get it running the file should look like this:

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6FBw.jpg)