# NuGet Pack error: The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I am following the [MS Instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio-net-framework) for preparing a NuGet Package on a .NET 4.7 Class Library I created with VS 2022.  Unlike the .NET 6 Library, there are no project properties that facilitate building a NuGet package.

When I run the command `nuget pack` I get this error.  Of course, if I look at the CSPROJ file, the namespace is on the `Project` element, so the error is not helpful.

Now, this differs from the other Q&A I found on StackExchange, because it occurs on the nuget pack command, so the other questions don't answer this one.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

The CSPROJ file is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{6A38AC27-E82D-47CF-B1C6-D987D7BCAE0C}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>CodaRESTClient.NET</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>CodaRESTClient.NET</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationIcon>Coda Logo - Image only.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.6.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.13.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RestSharp, Version=108.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\RestSharp.108.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\RestSharp.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Buffers, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Buffers.4.5.1\lib\net461\System.Buffers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Memory.4.5.4\lib\net461\System.Memory.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Numerics.Vectors.4.5.0\lib\net46\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.6.0.0\lib\net461\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Text.Encodings.Web, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Text.Encodings.Web.6.0.0\lib\net461\System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Text.Json, Version=6.0.0.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Text.Json.6.0.6\lib\net461\System.Text.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.5.4\lib\net461\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.ValueTuple.4.5.0\lib\net47\System.ValueTuple.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Client.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Client_Comment.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Client_Discussion.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Client_Errors.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Client_Moderator.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Client_Subscriptions.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Client_Troubleshoot.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Client_Vote.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SerializableDictionary.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="app.config" />
    <None Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Coda Logo - Image only.ico" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\System.Text.Json.6.0.6\build\System.Text.Json.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\System.Text.Json.6.0.6\build\System.Text.Json.targets')" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\System.Text.Json.6.0.6\build\System.Text.Json.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\System.Text.Json.6.0.6\build\System.Text.Json.targets'))" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

... and the NUSPEC file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <licenseUrl>https://licenses.nuget.org/CATOSL-1.1</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>https://github.com/info-tpr/CodaEA</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>https://www.codaea.io/images/CodaEA.png</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2022, The Parallel Revolution LLC, All Rights Reserved</copyright>
    <tags>error code analysis</tags>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

The full error message from nuget command is:

```
nuget : The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the <Project> element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.  
E:\Data\dotNetDev\codaea\CodaRESTServer\packages\System.Text.Json.6.0.6\build\System.Text.Json.targets
At line:1 char:1
+ nuget pack
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The default XML...xt.Json.targets:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Comment: Can you provide the code in .csproj and .nuspec to help reproduce the problem?

Comment: OK, files are above.

Comment: You are missing the default xml namespace (`xmlns=...`). [Here's an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#general-form-and-schema)

Comment: @Pieterjan I added the xmlns reference from the example you linked, to the <package> element just like the example.  Then, I executed `nuget pack` in the NuGet command line, and same error.  Incidentally, the project I am building aims to help developers provide better error messages in their apps - ironic.  But the error is not helpful!  Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you checke if this file(E:\Data\dotNetDev\codaea\CodaRESTServer\packages\System.Text.Json.6.0.6\build\System.Text.Json.targets) contains xmlns?

Comment: Hmm, a) no I did not check, b) how do I reference XMLNS in a JSON file?

Comment: Another question - does it matter if I don't use System.Text.Json?  I am using Newtonsoft instead...

Comment: System.Text.Json.targets should be an xml file. Add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" in this file may help you. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56427122/error-the-default-xml-namespace-of-the-project-must-be-the-msbuild-xml-namespac).

Comment: Ah, and so it is, sorry!  I added it to the <Project> tag like this:  <Project xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">.  Then, I tried "nuget pack" in the command console, but same error.

Comment: I still cannot reproduce the problem. Maybe you can try to clear the nuget cache in Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > General. Where are you using the nuget pack command? Is it in PM console or command prompt?

Comment: I don't know if you could reproduce the issue at will.  It is in the PM console. I have 2 projects I am packing - one is a .net 6 class library, that one packs great.  The other is .net framework 4.8 class library, that is the one I am having trouble with.

Comment: One thought occurred to me.  What if we could create a new, blank library that packs, and I can add my code to it?  Do you have any instructions for doing that specifically, or could you create one and post a link to it?  Maybe there's something messed up with my project, it has been around for 11 months before I tried to pack it.

Comment: Aha!  I noticed that the project now comes up in VS as unloaded, and when I try to load it, I get this error:  The default XML namespace ... and at the end, it has the path to the System.Text.json.targets file in a DIFFERENT project (the CodaRESTServer instead of CodaRESTClient).  Now, there is no dependency between the 2, so I don't know where that is coming from.

Comment: Also, if I start a totally new VS session, and just try to open the RESTClient vsproj file, it opens the entire solution with all 8 projects and fails on the RESTClient project...